# Assigning a function to a lambda assigns the calling function, not the specified one

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

I've got a piece of code in a train/shipping simulation that is giving me some unexpected results. In my code, I assign functions to lambdas, archive them onto a stack, and pop off the stack, completing each function in turn. Some functions put more functions on the stack.

I use lambdas so that when I put the function on the stack, it comes with the arguments that I want to run it with.

Here's my problem. I have a function called `TrainArrivesAtDock()` that is supposed to create another lambda and push it onto the stack. However, the lambda that I create doesn't hold the function I ask it to, it holds `TrainArrivesAtDock()`!

Here is the code:

```
event = lambda: TrainUnloadComplete(crew)
insertEventAtCorrectTime(currentTime + trainQueue[0].remainingUnloadTime, event)
```

but upon inspecting the event variable in my IDE, I see this: `<function TrainArrivesAtDock.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x0287BB28>`

Obviously this is not the correct implementation, but is it my fault or the interpreter's? I am using PyTools for VS2012, which I thought might be the problem, but running this program in IDLE produces the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code is probably functioning correctly. Consider the following example:

```
def get_lambda(closure_var):
    return lambda: closure_var

string = "Hey!"
foo = get_lambda(string)
print(foo)
print(foo())
```

With the output:

```
<function get_lambda.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f6b90281bf8>
Hey!
```

It appears that `TrainArrivesAtDock.<locals>.<lambda>` refers to the scope that the `lambda` was created in, presumably so that it can assess the necessary closure variables.

Answer (score 0):

If I run the following code under Python 3:

```
def main():
    x = lambda: print("hello")
    print(x)
    x()

main()
```

It prints:

```
<function main.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f39297012f0>
hello
```

Where the print of x prints the meta information for the lambda - it doesn't print the contents of the lambda, but where the lambda was defined.

Don't know why your code is not working, however I suspect you are on the wrong track.

Answer (score -2):

Wow, I'm stupid. Just as o_o comments above, the snippet my IDE gives me is referring to the location in which the lambda was created, not the lambda itself. This is a fault in my code, I misread the IDE.

Comment: This should rather be a comment to your question (or maybe an update to it).